# C# Task Independent Main Thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I Have A REST API and inside its POST action , I need to call method and don't wait for it and return result.

I need a methodology to guarantee that this method will be called and fully executed in background.

I Tried executing this method in Task but it failed sometimes and sometimes succeeded.

```
public string Post([FromBody]Accounts accounts)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
         ExecuteApi(); //I don't want to wait this method execution    
    });
    return "Success";
}
public void ExecuteApi(string request)
{
       string formattedResponse = "";
       string apiURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URL"];
       using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiURL);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
            MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
            string url = apiURL;
             StringContent contentA = new StringContent(request, 
            Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");

                var apiResponse = client.PostAsync(url, contentA).Result;
        }
}
```

Comment: you may want to try 'Asyn` with tasks. Or you can also use Dispatch Invoker.

Comment: *but it failed sometimes and sometimes succeeded*. So that code does work sometimes and sometimes it doesn't... Show that code!

Comment: If you don't want to wait this method execution - don't call it in controller action. Most likely your task is killed long before your `CallMethod()` is called.

Comment: _"it failed sometimes and sometimes succeeded"_ - what does that mean exactly? Does it sometimes not get called at all, or does it sometimes not finish? Can you debug and check: 1. Is it called in every call of Post? 2. Does it throw some exception?

Comment: 1. `var apiResponse = client.GetAsync(url).Result;` That's a NoNo! Go "async all the way" 2. [You are using HttpClient wrong](https://josefottosson.se/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/)

Comment: sometimes the call finished and sometime not

Comment: I Post action without waiting it to return , so I will edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Task.Run(..)` creates new `Task` instance which is doing some job. But you should be aware, that when your API send to your user `200 OK` (when you `return "Success"` and exit you `Post(..)` action) - your controller is disposed and this `Task` become "garbadge-collectable". So, sometimes your GC is fast enough to kill your `Task` before it executes, sometimes not.

You may think that storing your `Task` in a private field might be a good solution for this issue (spoiler: it's not)

```
private Task _aTask;

public string Post([FromBody]Accounts accounts)
{
    _aTask = Task.Run(() => ExecuteApi()); // this will not help
    return "Success";
}
```

This will not work as your controller instance is GC after your API call.

---

So now for the solutions:

**1. The best solution:** if you need it - `await` it.

```
public async Task<string> Post([FromBody]Accounts accounts)
{
    await ExecuteApiAsync();
    return "Success";
}

public async Task ExecuteApiAsync(string mobileNumber)
{
    // ...
    // WARNING! Bad use of HttpClient class here.
    // You should NOT create too many HttpClient instances eventhough you dispose them right.
    // Read this: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/330364/should-we-create-a-new-single-instance-of-httpclient-for-all-requests
    // and this: https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        // ...
        await client.GetAsync(url);
    }
}
```

**2. Good solution:** use [QueueBackgroundWorkItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.queuebackgroundworkitem) or any other 3rd party task schedulers. For example [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) or any other.

**3. Sort-of-good solution:** write your own task scheduler.

Comment: What about QueueBackgroundWorkItem (QBWI)?

Comment: @MohammedNasser, I have never work with this QBWI, but looks like it fits your needs. I will edit my answer.